# Type is missing the following properties from type in TypeScript of React-Native app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, class, interface

I have installed https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal library and I need to make a wrapper Modal class. The first initialize Interface. It extends from a few interfaces from react-native and react-native-modal libraries. It means I can use all properties from both of them:

```
import { ModalProps } from 'react-native';
import { ReactNativeModal, ModalProps as ModalRNProps } from 'react-native-modal';

export interface IModalProps extends Omit<ModalProps, 'onShow'>, ModalRNProps {
  showCloseButton?: boolean;
  showDoneBar?: boolean;
}

export class ModalNew extends React.Component<IModalProps> {
  public render() {
    const {
      style,
      children,
      showCloseButton,
      showDoneBar,
      animationType,
      onRequestClose,
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <ReactNativeModal
       isVisible={this.props.isVisible}
       onModalWillHide={onRequestClose}
       animationIn={'slideInUp'}
       animationOut={'slideOutDown'}
       animationOutTiming={600}
       useNativeDriver={true}
       backdropOpacity={0.6}
       backdropColor={theme.black}
       style={style}
       {...props}>
       {children}
      </ReactNativeModal>
    );
  }
}
```

But after when I use it in other component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ModalNew } from './ModalNew';

export class FooterHiddenPanel extends Component {
  const props = this.props;

  render() {
    return (
      <ModalNew isVisible={props.isActive} onRequestClose={props.onRequestClose}>
        <Text>This is </Text>
      </ModalNew>
    );
  }
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

It means I have to use all properties from both PropsTypes that I has extended my interface. But I don't need all of them. If I extend my class from a few interfaces I must implement all properties? Can you tell me please how can I get rid from this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided this error with Partial extends from react native modal props like this:

```
export interface IModalProps extends Partial<RNModalProps>, Omit<ModalProps, 'onShow'>, ThemeableProps {
  animationDuration?: number;
  showCloseButton?: boolean;
  showDoneBar?: boolean;
}
```